# AWS Lambda function is working with SAM Local tool but not on cloud

Tags: aws-lambda

My node.js Lambda function is working fine when I tested with SAM Local but the same code is giving the following error when I tested on aws cloud:

```
{"errorMessage": "RequestId: a36f187d-f8a1-11e8-a37c-c3f0418c02c9 Process exited before completing request"}
```

Any thoughts please.

Comment: You need to put more information, in some place in the message has the cause.

Comment: Show your code (at least the relevant parts) so we can see where the problem is.